# Skip the scan the task output when running a command from task.json

Tags: vscode-tasks

I have configured a [custom task](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) of type shell from vscode.

This task will be a simple one and I do not expect any errors, hence just to save one click, I would like to skip the prompt to `select for which kind of errors or warnings to scan the output`.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this or is this even possible? Many thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prompt can be skipped with setting `problemMatcher` property as empty array in specific task:

```
{
    "label": "echo hello world",
    "type": "shell",
    "command": "echo Hello",
    "problemMatcher": []
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The problem matcher microsoft won't tell you exists: []